# Different format for saving data in np.savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of data in a matrix form (different rows and columns). The elements of this matrix can vary from 1.e-7 to 1.e+8. The question is: Is there a way to loop or define (or an alternative way) of saving the elements based on their orders. For instance, if the element is less than 100 fmt = '%.3f' and if the element is more than 100 save in the scientific way in np.savetxt python?

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier `%g` is a quick/clean way to select the form
depending on the input (see [savetxt docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)):

> g,G : use the shorter of e,E or f

As an example:

```
X = 10.0**np.arange(-10,10, 3)
np.savetxt("foo.txt", X, fmt="%5g")
```

Gives you output with the more extreme values in standard form ("scientific notation"), but those closer to 1 in a plainer format.

```
$ cat foo.txt
1e-10
1e-07
0.0001
  0.1
  100
100000
1e+08
```